# Facebook, IOS and a business page

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

I have a client with a business Facebook page. I can see their feeds without being logged in thru my web browser. How can I access that info through iOS without needing any user authentication.

I can see it in a web browser when I'm not logged in, and I would think OpenGraph could do it too. I know how to query, Im just not getting anything but basic user data.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When I go to `https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/` without an access token, I can see the basic information for the cocacola page.  However, if I try to access their feed: `https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/feed` I am required to use an access token.  Any valid access token when added to the query string worked.  `https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/feed?access_token=AVal1dAcc3sT0k3nHer3`

This appears to be a requirement for access to using Facebook's Graph API. See https://developers.facebook.com/policy/ Policies I. 3. "*You must not circumvent (or claim to circumvent) our intended limitations on core Facebook features and functionality./*"